# Criteria for Time fields

Tags: ms-access

I am trying to write the criteria for a query a query that is pulling all rows from a table that does NOT have a time of 11:00AM or anything that starts at half past the hour. (ie 10:30, 11:30, 12:30 etc.) I have searched for examples but have not had any luck. I figured out pretty easily on how to adjust the 11:00 am time but I cannot figure out how to filter on anything that has a time of XX:30?

Comment: Try something like:  WHERE (((Format([MyTime],"n"))<>30));

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you!

Comment: @WayneG.Dunn edit -- I thought it did..i get a type mismatch error. THe appt time field is an actual date/time and I believe the criteria you gave me would work for a string but not a date/time

Comment: I used that with a field defined as Date/Time, but yes, it does return a string value.   You can use  WHERE (((Minute([MyTime]))<>30));

Comment: @WayneG.Dunn The second suggestion worked without error. I tried to mimic the same issue I had with your first suggestion and no longer receive it using it in the same query. I am not sure why I received a type mismatch error the first time, thank you for showing more than one way to accomplish this I didn't have any luck using Microsoft's website.